# How to do CudaMemcpy using CUdeviceptr

Tags: c#, c++, cuda

I'm trying to do a wrapper in a С++ DLL for CUDA, to be able to use it in C# (yeah, I know there's managedCuda and cudafy, but I still would like to try this)

The thing is, to be able to pass the pointer reference back to c#, i cant just do as usual and do the cuda malloc with float*. I was trying to manage everything with CUdeviceptr, but, even though cudaMalloc apparently works (no error given by cudaGetLastError), when I do the cudaMemcpy using the CUdevicptr variable it breaks and gives the "Invalid argument" error.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl allocateDeviceMemory(float*, CUdeviceptr,     unsigned int);

extern void allocateDeviceMemory(float* data, CUdeviceptr device_pointer, unsigned int numElements){
cudaMalloc((void**)&device_pointer,numElements * sizeof(float));
cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
printf("CudaError.... 1  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));

cudaMemcpy((void*)&device_pointer ,data,numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
error = cudaGetLastError();
printf("CudaError.... 2  %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas about how can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
cudaMemcpy((void*)&device_pointer ,data,numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```

to

```
cudaMemcpy((void *)device_pointer ,data,numElements * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice
```

`CUdeviceptr` itself is a device **pointer**. When you are doing `&device_pointer`, you are sending in the pointer to the device pointer. `cudaMalloc` expects a pointer to pointer and works fine. `cudaMemcpy` however expects only a device pointer (not pointer to pointer).

---

- If you want to use the driver API (i.e. use `CUdeviceptr`), use [`cuMemAlloc`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1gb82d2a09844a58dd9e744dc31e8aa467) and [`cuMemcpyHtoD`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MEM.html#group__CUDA__MEM_1g4d32266788c440b0220b1a9ba5795169)
- If you want to use the runtime API use `void *` for memory pointers and cast them to the required type. You can use `cudaMalloc` and `cudaMemcpy` with the runtime API.

**EDIT:** Added edit to explicitly cast `CUdeviceptr` to `void *`. Added information about driver and device API.

Comment: Well, actually, I had tried that first, and it gave me the following compilation error: argument of type "CUdeviceptr" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *" Thats why I had tried using the cast

Comment: cast device_pointer to void* but don't reference it, so like the first code line in Pavan Yalamanchili's answer but without the "&"

Comment: @gumlym You can explicitly cast them like kunzmi mentions. But, ideally, you should be using the driver API or the device API. Don't try to mix them. Check my edit for more information.